# Segmentation fault relating to the main statement - Using C++, SDL

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sdl, program-entry-point

Im using C++ and SDL to program a game, and even though I get no errors whenever I try to run it - I get a segmentation fault. I ran the gdb debugger and this is what it gave me when I used the backtrack function :    "#0  main () at main.cpp:10" , where the 10th line is the statement right after the try block opens. Can someone tell me what is going on here, Ive never encountered such an error before.

Comment: It's difficult to tell you what's going on, because you haven't posted a [complete test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Should I perhaps paste my manager's play function in here?

Comment: @K.G - I tried that, its not working.

Comment: If it's less than ~10 lines of code, then yes.  If it's not less than ~10 lines, start to simplify it until it *is* that short.  You will probably discover the problem in the process.

Comment: Could the problem be in the Manager constructor? Does it still segfault if you comment out `play`?

Comment: @Jesse Vogt - Good point, I think. I commented out play and it still gives the segmentation fault. I know there can't be anything wrong with the Manager class, because I used the same code for a previous framework too and it worked fine.

Comment: Could you post the Manager default constructor and destructor?

Comment: Use Valgrind to run a debug-enabled (with symbols and non-optimized etc) binary and see the call stack in the Valgrind report. Usually helps to figure out such cases quickly and painlessly.

Comment: This is what I get when I use Valgrind :

Comment: Continuation :  by 0x403D21: Player::Player(Vector2f, Vector2f, std::string const&, Frame const*) (player.h:7)
==6763==    by 0x40322C: Manager::Manager() (manager.cpp:35)
==6763==    by 0x402BFB: main (main.cpp:10)
==6763==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6763==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6763==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6763==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6763==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.

Comment: Does this mean that the root of the problem is at Frame's getWidth() function??

Comment: @JesseVogt - Ive added the constructor and destructor to the main question.

Comment: @TristaN: All new information should be in the question, not the comments.  Comments can be and are deleted without warning.

Comment: Haven't used SDL in years - is Frame part of your framework or is it coming from somewhere else? If it is yours can you post the code?

Comment: The call to `&frame[0]` in the initializer list for the `player` member looks a bit suspicious since I don't see `frame` initialized - where is that coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are creating the `SDL_Surface`s for `bgSurface` and `fgSurface` *before* calling `SDL_Init`...

That's why I have the call to `SDL_Init` in a class constructor, by itself (and `SDL_Quit` in the constructor). That way you can just make `Manager` a private subclass of that one:

```
class Manager : private SDLInitializer
{ /* */  }
```

And in the constructor:

```
Manager::Manager() : 
    SDLInitializer(SDL_INIT_VIDEO),
    /* */
```

And since base classes are initialized before member variables, all goes well!

Comment: I can also call SDL_INIT_VIDEO in main.cpp before the manager object is created right?